# Solution of two quadratic equation with a particular structure

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-curves

> I have a system of two quadratic equations with unknowns $x$ and $y$ and the following structure
>
> \begin{cases}
> 0=ax^2-bxy+kx-r_1y+c_1\\
> 0=by^2-axy-kx-r_2y+c_2
> \end{cases}

where all parameters are nonzero positive scalars, except $a$ and $c_2$ that could also be negative.

Is there a special algebraic solution for the above system? Is there any possibility to get a unique solution?

Comment: So $c_2$ is nonzero or can it be zero?

Comment: all parameters are non-zero

Comment: This is equivalent to cubic equation (no $y^2$ term) so you may have one or three solutions in real numbers. Algebraic solutions of the cubic can be obatained using Cardano's formulas. So at least one solution should exist.